# How can I dispatch an NGRX action when query params of an URL change?

Tags: angular, ngrx

How would you dispatch a ngrx action when the query params of an URL change? I have an URL with parameters (for example http://myapp.my/documents?startdate=2015-04-04&enddate=2015-06-06 ) and when user clicks the back (forward) browser button, angular will navigate to the previous (next) URL which might have different search parameters. So I need to dispatch a "load documents" action to load corresponding docs from DB. I can see multiple ways to do it.

1. I could bind a ngrx @Effect to the angular-router
   "navigationend" Observable and check if the URL matches
   "/documents". the effect would dispatch a load documents action
2. I could bind an ngrx @Effect to ROUTER_NAVIGATION Action produced by ngrx/router-store and have a action. Problem here is that ROUTER_NAVIGATION does not guarantee that the user will really get to the intended page (for example they could be blocked by a route guard),
3. I could dispatch the action inside canActivate() guard of the "documents" path - maybe other problems are hiding here (Edit: tested this and it does not work because canActivate is only called once. It is not called again when URL parameters change.)
4. some better way?

Angular 5, ngrx 4.

Comment: can you paste your component code where you are fetching data from routeParam.

Comment: I am working with an ngrx store, route parameters are only used to dispatch a new LoadDocuments(filterParams:any) action which will then load documents from server. The loaded documents are pushed into ngrx store. The component listens to the ngrx store and updates itself to reflect new components in the store. The issue is how to dispatch the LoadDocuments action when route params change.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use [`@ngrx/router-store`](https://github.com/ngrx/platform) to add the current route to the store, then you can subscribe to the current route params like

```
this.store.select('routerReducer', 'state', 'params').subscribe(params => {
  // do stuff
})
```

`select` should automatically de-duplicate `params` for you, ensuring that you only dispatch actions when the route params change. You can also modify this to make use of `.pipe()`, if appropriate. Or make an `@Effect()` that watches the router and does stuff. `@ngrx/router-store` has solutions for all of this.

[Version 4.1.1 docs](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/v4.1.1/docs/router-store/README.md) **<-- edit: these docs are now outdated**

Comment: Nice. I am already using @ngrx/router-store and effects. I just didn't think of creating an effect which would subscribe to changes in state. All my current effects subscribe to actions only.

Comment: @nothinkelse if you only want things to be dispatched if the user is viewing a specific route (read: has a specific component loaded), you should simply subscribe to the params in that route's (component's) `ngOnInit()` call. If someone presses the browser's back button, and the only thing that changes are some params, then angular will reuse the already loaded component (meaning ngOnInit won't be called again) and your subscription will update. This will also ensure that the `subscribe` block won't be called if they aren't viewing that route.

Comment: Nice. It works. + I unsubscribe on ngOnDestroy ( http://brianflove.com/2016/12/11/anguar-2-unsubscribe-observables/ ).

Comment: @nothinkelse ya, do that too :)

Answer (score -2):

Use following code:

```
this.route.params.subscribe(param: ParamMap => {
  // dispatched your action to fetch data
  this.store.dispatch(new YourAction.YourActionMethod());
  // When your store will update then subscribe will fired
  this.store.select(reducers.YourReducer).subscribe((data) => {
    if (data) {
      // use your data here
    }
  });
});
```

Hope it will help

Comment: Avoid nested subscribes